# Swashbuckle with F#: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, f#, swashbuckle

I created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` in C# and followed [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). It worked great.

I did the same thing in F# and ran into this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to 
find the required services. Please add all 
the required services by calling 
'IServiceCollection.AddMvc' inside the call 
to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the 
application startup code.'
```

Here is the Startup.fs

```
namespace ASPNETSwagger

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger

type Startup () =
    new (configuration: IConfiguration) as this =
        Startup() then
        this.Configuration <- configuration

    member _this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2) |> ignore
        services.AddSwaggerGen(fun c -> c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info(Title = "My API", Version = "v1")))

    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IHostingEnvironment) =
        app.UseSwagger() |> ignore
        app.UseSwaggerUI(fun c -> c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1")) |> ignore

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) then
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
        else
            app.UseHsts() |> ignore

        app.UseHttpsRedirection() |> ignore
        app.UseMvc() |> ignore

    member val Configuration : IConfiguration = null with get, set
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [this documentation](https://sergeytihon.com/2015/09/06/swagger-for-f-web-apps/). Maybe it helps you.

Comment: *'I did the same thing in F#'* does not explain what exactly you did in F#

Comment: The documentation you posted is for ASP.NET Web API which runs on the .NET Framework and unfortunately does not apply.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I added my Startup.fs file to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(fun c -> c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info(Title = "My API", Version = "v1")))
```

is an expression returning an `IServiceCollection`. The containing method `ConfigureServices` needs to return `unit`. So, adding an `|> ignore` to the end of that line or `()` as the last line fixes the signature.

In addition, this line

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(fun c -> c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1")) |> ignore
```

needs to be

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(fun c -> c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1")) |> ignore
```

It was missing a leading `/`.

Comment: Adding an explicit return type to methods like ConfigureServices prevents type inference from breaking the contract.